# Sass color mix function produce different results for different ruby versions

Tags: css, ruby, sass, compass

Color output after compiling sass files differed between ruby 2.1.6 and 2.2.2. Is this a freak occurrence, or can we expect the mix function do produce different values if we upgrade Ruby in the future?

```
// test.scss
$white: white;
$black: black;
$dark-text: #2e3135;
$offwhite: #f7f8f8;
$error: #e32908;

.mixed {
  color: mix($white, $black);
  color: mix($black, $error);
  color: mix($dark-text, $offwhite);
}
```

Compiled with 2.1.6

```
//ruby 2.1.6p336 (2015-04-13 revision 50298) [x64-mingw32]
//Compass 1.0.3 (Polaris)
//Sass 3.4.13 (Selective Steve)

.mixed {
  color: #7f7f7f;
  color: #711404;
  color: #929496;
}
```

Compiled with 2.2.2

```
//ruby 2.2.2p95 (2015-04-13 revision 50295) [x64-mingw32]
//Compass 1.0.3 (Polaris)
//Sass 3.4.15 (Selective Steve):

.mixed {
  color: gray;
  color: #721504;
  color: #939597;
}
```

The color differences are pretty minor, so it doesn't matter, but it would be interesting to know what happened.

Comment: Are you certain your Sass version did not change as well?

Comment: I had forgotten to check the Sass version - I only checked the Compass version and those were the same. The Sass version had changed, but only the patch version. I'll update the question with the versions.

Comment: Yeah, that seems to be it. I would feel that changing how calculations work would warrant more than the patch version being increased, but that's just me.

Comment: Your question as is stated now cannot be reproduced. And you have found out that that is the case.

Comment: Of course it can be reproduced. Steps to reproduce: 1. Install one version of Ruby mentioned in the question. 2. Install compass. 3. Compile. 4. Do the same for the other version.

Comment: Note that I did not install Sass explicitly and that the Compass version was the same - which I guess is the reason I didn't check the Sass version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found this in the [Sass changelog](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_CHANGELOG.html#3415_22_june_2015) after the comment from @cimmanon

## 3.4.15 (22 June 2015)

- Further improve rounding for various numeric operations.
- Imp rounding in operator-based color operations.

Comment: I'll leave this up here in case someone is as confused as I am =)

Comment: @mfodin Mark it as accepted to let the community know the answer.

Comment: @TylerH Will do, but have to wait two days to accept own answer.